# Exclude row from MySQL older than today

Tags: mysql

There is a MySQL *table*:

```
+----+-------+------+------------+---------+
| id | name  | type |    date    | deleted |
+----+-------+------+------------+---------+
| 1  | nameA |  1   | 2016:10:15 |    1    |
+----+-------+------+------------+---------+
| 2  | nameB |  1   | 2016:10:20 |    0    |
+----+-------+------+------------+---------+
| 3  | nameC |  2   | 2016:09:26 |    0    |
+----+-------+------+------------+---------+
| 4  | nameD |  2   | 2016:09:30 |    0    |
+----+-------+------+------------+---------+
| 5  | nameE |  3   | 2016:09:26 |    0    |
+----+-------+------+------------+---------+
```

I want to `SELECT` everything except where deleted = 1 and except where type = 2 has a date older than today (2016:09:27). So I tried using `NOT IN`, but the way I do it excludes also type=3 which has a date older than today:

```
$currentDate = date("Y:m:d");
$sql = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE deleted != 1 AND date NOT IN       
   (SELECT date FROM table WHERE type = 2 AND date < '$currentDate') ORDER BY date";
```

Any help? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it like this:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE deleted = 0 AND NOT (type = 2 AND date < DATE(NOW())) ORDER BY date";
```

I don't think you need to define currentDate in PHP either.

Answer (score 2):

**Table Structure:**

```
CREATE TABLE `example` (
`id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
`name` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
`type` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
`date` date DEFAULT NULL,
`deleted` int(11) DEFAULT NULL
)

/*Data for the table `example` */

insert  into `example`(`id`,`name`,`type`,`date`,`deleted`) values (1,'nameA',1,'2016-10-15',1),(2,'nameB',1,'2016-10-20',0),(3,'nameC',2,'2016-09-26',0),(4,'nameD',2,'2016-09-30',0),(5,'nameE',3,'2016-09-28',0),(6,'nameE',3,'2016-09-26',0);
```

**Required Query:**

```
SELECT * FROM EXAMPLE WHERE (deleted != 1 AND id NOT IN (SELECT id FROM EXAMPLE WHERE (TYPE = 2 AND  DATE < CURDATE()))) ORDER BY DATE
```

Comment: Thanks but in this case row with a type = 2 AND date **newer** than today will be excluded too.

Comment: You mentioned older than today, so today is not older than today. check the amended query, now it should  also work for today.

Comment: That's not the point. Ok, so will the row with the id = 4 be printed with your query?

Comment: No, because its type = 2.

Comment: Right, and my condition says that it should be printed out if it has date newer than today event though it is type 2 :)

Comment: please verify output of amended query.

Answer (score 0):

Use `Str_to_date`

```
SELECT * FROM table 
WHERE deleted != 1 
AND date NOT IN       
(SELECT date FROM table 
WHERE type = 2 AND  str_to_date(date, '%Y:%m:%d' )  < curdate()) 
ORDER BY str_to_date(date", '%Y:%m:%d')
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a fundamental mistake in your database structure.
If you want to compare dates and times effectively, you need to use the appropriate datatype `DATETIME`. Don't use a string - MySQL can't tell how to order the results or what is lower or higher.

Change the type to `DATETIME` and form your query like:

```
WHERE datetime_column < DATE_SUB(CURDATE(),  INTERVAL 1 DAY)
```

If you don't want to use the time at all, use `DATE` instead of `DATETIME`.